# Git Repository Manager conditionally deny pull request

Tags: git, repository

I am looking to migrate a handful of Subversion repositories to Git. Each of these repositories has a development and production branch. When ready to release, a developer will submit a pull request to production. There is a version file that contains the version that has to be incremented in some way. Is there a Git repository manager (Gitlab, Bitbucket, etc.) that allows you to automatically deny pull requests based on a condition? My condition in this example would be the version in a version file is not incremented. I am also willing to consider other methods, such as tagging the repositories instead of a version file, if auto-denying in that way is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most repository managers have some way of implementing this.

GitHub (and GitHub Enterprise) has the idea of statuses on a commit; you'd set up [a webhook](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) that pings your tool's webserver when a commit is pushed, and then it would use [the status API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statuses/) to set whether or not it passes the version check.

Bitbucket, when self-hosted, supports plugins to integrate nicely with it, including [ScriptRunner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.stash.groovy.groovyrunner/server/overview), which can be used to do all sorts of things similar to what you want.

I'm not familiar with GitLab, but it probably has some similar method.

You will need to do some programming to implement the checking logic, but these pieces should allow you to kick that off when appropriate and use the results to block the merge.